# What should be the access modifier of ServiceImpl Class?

Tags: java, clean-architecture, access-modifiers

A class `CorporateServiceImpl` is implementing an interface called `CorporateService`. Here I know that the `CorporateServiceImpl` class never be used outside of the package. I will use the implemented method of the `CorporateServiceImpl` through the interface. In that case, what should be the access modifier of the `CorporateServiceImpl` class? Currently, I am preferring `protected` so that other classes of the package could use this. Is my implementation correct? Or it should be public?

Comment: If it were me, I would use public. 
Especially this kind of service class that may be subject to dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

totally up to you, if you will not use it outside the package, use default modifier.

Answer (score -1):

You always have to use at least one Public Class in your java file, otherwise it won't be compiled to .class file in JVM. Only methods and fields are behaved as private or protected. If you want to have a private or protected class for example, you need to declare them in another Public class.

Comment: Please, where did you get that from? A top-level must not be `protected` or `private`, but it may be `public` **or** have *package-access*

Comment: You are asking about protected modifier in a top-level class, not about an inner class. So you have to use at least one Public class.

Comment: You can check all these modifiers in your system and see what happens. You can not use protected for a separate interface, it can only be public or null (package), because it stands for a .java file. Also an implementation of an interface in another standalone file can be public or package, not private or protected. This is different for inner classes and interfaces.

Comment: package has no modifier access. Also your question was about public vs protected access modifier in an interface and the implementation of that, not about package modifier. I'm not answering about other situations. But generally you are right and a standalone java file can have either public or package access in top-level.